# Alternative ways to express "Examples of Something"

Tags: expressions, sentence, writing-style, phrase-requests

I am conceiving the title of a web page where a number of examples will be listed.

I can use the page title "Examples of Something" e.g. "Examples of Cars",  "Examples of Jobs" and "Examples of Fruits" but I'm looking for a more fashion, business-friendly, title-appealing way to title the page, perhaps using a two-word title.

Are there alternative ways to express "Examples of Something"?

Answer (score 1):

Although examples is probably the most widely used and most to the point, yes there are other alternatives, such as:

1. Samples of _______
2. Illustrations of _______ (If that works with what you are doing)
3. You could simply use ______ Examples to eliminate the "of"
4. The topic that you are writing on: Ex. Electric cars
5. The reasoning behind ______

Answer (score 0):

There is the two word combination of the type of "fruit specimens". ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fruit%20specimen%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))